# Making Slider thumb progression moving smoothly, in UWP Xaml

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to use Slider as a progress bar. I have a binding of this slider value. This binding is being triggered per second (Timer is used, Time elapsed triggers, interval is 1 second, it is needed). The problem is, Slider's Thumb is not smoothly moving, per second it jumps to the next position. How can I make it smooth? For example:

```
int time = 0;
Time_Elapsed(sender, args){
    time++;
    CheckTime();
}
CheckTime(){
    if(time == 60){
        SliderValue = (time*100)/totalTime;
        time = 0;
    }
} 
SliderValue{
    get{ return sliderValue;}
    set{ SetProperty(ref sliderValue, value);}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Slider Value={Binding SliderValue,Mode=TwoWay}
        Maximum=100
        Minimum=0/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Khaled said, if you want to move the thumb smoothly, using a timer is not a recommended practice.

At this time, you can use `Storyboard`:

```xml
<Page
    ...
    Loaded="Page_Loaded">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="SliderAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TestSlider"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                             EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                             From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:10"
                             />
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" x:Name="TestSlider"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```cs
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SliderAnimation.Begin();
}
```

This animation shows that within 10 seconds, `Slider.Value` goes from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

The behavious you're seeing is the expected one since you are setting the Value property to an exact value. For animation you should take a look at [Storybords and animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations). Sorry never had to use it so I don't have a working example.